# Making a backup creator

Tags: c, backup, patch

I am helping develop a program that makes an easy way to backup a specific file format in the form of an [ips patch](http://romhack.wikia.com/wiki/IPS). We want it to compare 2 files, one in the program folder with a specific name(for ease) and then another that's user selected, which will then produce a patch with the current date/time as the file name. We are coding in C. Are there any tips on to how we can manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to find an existing IPS implementation in the form of either:

1. A pre-existing library plus API
2. A pre-existing project

Fortunately for you, Neill Corlett (the wonderful guy who made the English translation of ["Secret of Mana 2" / "Seiken Densetsu 3"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seiken_Densetsu_3) a reality) has already created an [openly available implementiation of the UPS and IPS patch generation/application algorithms](http://ftp.availo.se/pub/pkgsrc/distfiles/uips-1.0/uips.c). [Please refer to the associated readme file to determine the licensing terms](http://ftp.availo.se/pub/pkgsrc/distfiles/uips-1.0/uips.txt).

Anyhow, you can just modify the `main()` function in the program to select two particular file names (his existing program is already designed to accept them as command-line arguments), and the work is passed off the the existing functions that handle patch generation/application.

Good luck!

Comment: @JoeOliveira You can accept the question by clicking the checkmark next to the up/down-vote buttons. Cheers!